# aggregate function in R, multiple conditions

Tags: r, data-management

I don't get the right way to compute a new column which contains a sum up of a column in a data frame by aggregating anothor column by a grep function. The data frame looks like follows:

```
   ID_Oeffnungszeit ID_Einrichtung Anzahl_Std Bez_Oeffnungszeit
                 1        3000001       0.50  Montag Vormittag
                 1        3000003       3.00  Montag Vormittag
                 1        3000008       2.50  Montag Vormittag
                 2        3000001       1.00  Montag Nachmittag
                 4        3000003       1.50  Dienstag Vormittag
                 1        3000023       1.00  Montag Vormittag
                 1        3000025       1.00  Montag Vormittag
                 1        3000026       1.00  Montag Vormittag
                 3        3000001       2.00  Montag Abend
                            ...
                 1        3000038       3.50  Montag Vormittag
                          and so on...
```

There are 21 characteristics for the variable `Bez_Oeffnungszeit`, but they can be categorized due to the fact if they contain the words `Vormittag`, `Nachmittag` or `Abend`.
So I would like to generate a new column which contains the sums of the column `Anzahl_Std` for each `ID_Einrichtung` depending on which word the `Bez_Oeffnungszeit` contains.

I'm quite sure that I should use the `grep` and the `by` functions, but I couldn't manage to make the it work in my sense...

```
df <- structure(list(ID_Oeffnungszeit = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "3"), ID_Einrichtung = c(3000001L, 3000003L, 3000008L, 
3000001L, 3000003L, 3000023L, 3000025L, 3000026L, 3000001L), 
    Anzahl_Std = c(0.5, 3, 2.5, 1, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 2), Bez_Oeffnungszeit = c("Montag Vormittag", 
    "Montag Vormittag", "Montag Vormittag", "Montag Nachmittag", 
    "Dienstag Vormittag", "Montag Vormittag", "Montag Vormittag", 
    "Montag Vormittag", "Montag Abend")), .Names = c("ID_Oeffnungszeit", 
"ID_Einrichtung", "Anzahl_Std", "Bez_Oeffnungszeit"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: It will help if you use `dput` to include sample data, particularly since you have spaces in the last column.

Comment: I added the dput for the first few rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a new column only containing the word  "Vormittag", "Nachmittag" or "Abend" and then use that as a grouping variable.

For instance:

```
# Set random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)

# Make some data
my.data <- data.frame(ID_Oeffnungszeit = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
                   ID_Einrichtung = sample(3000001:3000020, 100, replace = TRUE),
                   Anzahl_Std = rnorm(100),
                   Bez_Oeffnungszeit = sample(c("Montag Vormittag",
                                                "Montag Nachmittag",
                                                "Dienstag Vormittag", 
                                                "Montag Abend"), 100, 
                                                replace = T))

# Create a new column containing "Vormittag", "Nachmittag" or "Abend"
my.data$cat <- ""
my.data$cat[grep("Vormittag", my.data$Bez_Oeffnungszeit)] <- "Vormittag"
my.data$cat[grep("Nachmittag", my.data$Bez_Oeffnungszeit)] <- "Nachmittag"
my.data$cat[grep("Abend", my.data$Bez_Oeffnungszeit)] <- "Abend"

# Now just call aggregate over the Std variable using ID and category
# as grouping factors.
res <- aggregate(my.data$Anzahl_Std, 
                 by = list(ID = my.data$ID_Einrichtung, cat = my.data$cat), 
                 FUN = sum)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: **Supplement:**
Is there maybe a possibility to put into the new df only a subsetted version of the results? For example just rows of `my.data$cat["Vormittag"]`.

Could you maybe show the way also with ddply? 

I tried: 
`res <- ddply(my.data, .(ID_Oeffnugszeit, cat["Ja"]), sum(Anzahl_Std))`,
but it's false.

However, ddply seems to be more appropriate for aggregations like that..

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option *(using the data mentioned in the question)*

```
library(splitstackshape)
```

**step1:** Using splitstackshape's `cSplit` function to split the column `Bez_Oeffnungszeit` in `wide` format taking advantage of the space between the two words.
    This will generate two columns `'Bez_Oeffnungszeit_1'` containing the first word and `'Bez_Oeffnungszeit_2'` with the second word which is further used in second step

```
dt = cSplit(df, 'Bez_Oeffnungszeit', ' ', 'wide')
```

**step2:** We use the `'Bez_Oeffnungszeit_2'`containing the words of interest and `'ID_Einrichtung'` column to sum `'Anzahl_Std'` using `data.table` syntax

```
dt[order(Bez_Oeffnungszeit_2), .(New = sum(Anzahl_Std)), 
            by = .(ID_Einrichtung, Bez_Oeffnungszeit_2)]

#output looks like:

#   ID_Einrichtung Bez_Oeffnungszeit_2 New
#1:        3000001               Abend 2.0
#2:        3000001          Nachmittag 1.0
#3:        3000001           Vormittag 0.5
#4:        3000003           Vormittag 4.5
#5:        3000008           Vormittag 2.5
#6:        3000023           Vormittag 1.0
#7:        3000025           Vormittag 1.0
#8:        3000026           Vormittag 1.0
```

Comment: Not familiar with splitstackshape, could you explain what the code is doing? Where is `Bez_Oeffnungszeit_2` coming from?

Comment: @nico I have added the description to my answer. hope I made it clear enough